# What is the dimension of solution space of a differential equation of first order, nth degree?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I've recently started linear algebra and got an important point that 
*dimension of solution space of a differential equation = order of the differential equation *
Now I get a differential equation having order one but it is of 2nd degree. It is actually of the type *left hand side resolvable into factors *. So I got two solutions for it, corresponding to each factors equal to zero.
But those two solutions are linearly independent. Isn't this mean that they're two basis for the solution space and hence dimension of the original differential equation is 2?

Comment: What do you mean by «a differential equation having order one but it is of 2nd degree» Is the equation not linear?

Comment: It is p^2 - p[e^(x) + e^(-x)] + 1 = 0 ; p= dy/dx

Comment: Since that is not a linear equation, then its set of solutions does not have any sensible vector space structure so your question does not really make sense.

Comment: Oh! That's what I didn't know that if differential equation is non linear then its solutions can't span a vector space.